# Onclick method in another onclick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a todo list with react. When I click the create task button it creates a div with a delete button in it. I want to be able to click the delete button to delete that task but instead it deletes all of the tasks and no more tasks can be added after that. I also tried using useState but nothing was being deleted.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import DelIcon from './assets/close-btn.png';
import './styling/home.scss';

let taskArr = [];

function Task(todo) {
    this.todo = todo;
}

function home() {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    const [deleteTask, setDelete] = useState(false);

    const taskContainer = document.createElement('div');
    taskContainer.className = 'task-container';
    document.body.appendChild(taskContainer);

    let taskDiv = document.querySelector('.task-div');

    const handleDel = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < taskArr.length; i++) {
            taskContainer.remove(taskDiv);
            taskArr.splice(taskDiv, 1);
        }
    };

    console.log(deleteTask);

    const handleClick = () => {
        let todo = inputRef.current.value;
        let newTask = new Task(todo);
        taskArr.push(newTask);
        console.log(taskArr);
        inputRef.current.value = '';

        if (taskArr[taskArr.length - 1] !== '') {
            const taskDiv = document.createElement('div');
            taskDiv.className = 'task-div';

            const taskText = document.createElement('p');
            const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

            taskText.innerText = taskArr[taskArr.length - 1].todo;
            taskContainer.appendChild(taskDiv);
            taskDiv.appendChild(taskText);
            taskDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);
            taskContainer.appendChild(taskDiv);

            deleteBtn.innerHTML = `<img src=${DelIcon} alt='delete-btn' />`;
            deleteBtn.className = 'delete-btn';
            deleteBtn.onclick = handleDel;
        }
    };
    return (
        <div id='home-container'>
            <input type='text' ref={inputRef} maxLength={40} />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default home;
```

Comment: Your code is absolutely not efficient with React. I suggest you to read a good tuto.

Comment: I would look at the [how-to documentation for React](https://react.dev/) rather than a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that the handleDel function deletes all tasks from the taskContainer every time it's called. Instead, you should delete only the specific task associated with the delete button that was clicked.

Here's a modified version of your code that should work as expected:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DelIcon from './assets/close-btn.png';
import './styling/home.scss';

function Task(todo) {
  this.todo = todo;
}

function Home() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const handleDelete = (index) => {
    const updatedTasks = [...tasks];
    updatedTasks.splice(index, 1);
    setTasks(updatedTasks);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    const todo = inputRef.current.value;
    const newTask = new Task(todo);
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
    inputRef.current.value = '';
  };

  return (
    <div id='home-container'>
      <input type='text' ref={inputRef} maxLength={40} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
      <div className='task-container'>
        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
          <div className='task-div' key={index}>
            <p>{task.todo}</p>
            <button className='delete-btn' onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>
              <img src={DelIcon} alt='delete-btn' />
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Hope this could solve your problem.